# Rails getting error when generating shopify app

Tags: shopify

I'm getting an error when generating shopify app using rails. Screenshot is shown below:

[image: error img]

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably added the shopify gem to the gems file.
all you need to do is to run

```
bundle install
```

so the app will install and use the new gem

Comment: I had run bundle install command multiple times but getting same error :(